# When trying to create a Facebook app it triggers error message in the application domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps, osclass, facebook-app-settings

I'm trying to create a Facebook application for using the login with Facebook plugin for OSClass. I tried to add the domain in the following ways: https://www.example.com , http://www.example.com , www.example.com , all of them triggers the following error message (translated from spanish)

> The application domains must match with the URL domains of Facebook
>   games (https), URL for mobile websites, Unity binary URL, website URL
>   or secure URL of the Facebook page tab. Fix the following domains :
>   www.example.com

Someone mentioned elsewhere to validate that the website it's yours. Is this true? I dont recall doing this in the past with Facebook apps. What else can be wrong here?

Comment: _When_ do you get this message, what are you trying to do at this point?

Comment: I'm trying to save the changes done to the app settings

Comment: And, have you configured any of the platforms the error message mentions?

Comment: I just found what it was, I had an application created several years ago with the same domain. For some reason it triggers that message which isnt very descriptive.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever - multiple apps can be configured for the same domain, no problem.

Comment: May be it is a bug, but now it's working.